# Input unicode string with pyautogui

Tags: unicode, pyautogui

I'm creating an autotesting app with `pyautogui` lib. I want to use `typewrite` method to input text into forms. But some of my input strings have unicode characters in them. For example:

> Næst

According to documentation `typewrite` can only press single-character keys. So it just ignores the `æ` character.

Can you advise some simple workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found one quite simple one.

In Mac and Linux there is an opportunity to input unicode characters using their hex codes. There is [article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#Hexadecimal_code_input) about that. I'm writing my program for Mac so I enabled Unicode Hex Input in my keyboard settings and wrote this code:

```
def type_unicode(word):
    for c in word:
        c = '%04x' % ord(c)
        pyautogui.keyDown('optionleft')
        pyautogui.typewrite(c)
        pyautogui.keyUp('optionleft')
```

Answer (score 43):

I know this thread is old, but for the sake of the topic I managed to get around it using pyperclip in an easier manner in my opinion.

Rather than trying to make pyautogui to type special characters, copy them to the clipboard using pyperclip and then use pyautogui to paste them. For instance on Windows:

```py
import pyautogui
import pyperclip

pyperclip.copy("It's leviOsa, not lêvioçÁ!")
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
```

EDIT:

We can make it work in multiple platforms as below (thanks @karlo for pointing it out):

```py
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import platform

def type(text: str):    
    pyperclip.copy(text)
    if platform.system() == "Darwin":
        pyautogui.hotkey("command", "v")
    else:
        pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")


type("It's leviOsa, not lêvioçÁ!")
```

Comment: On Max OS X, I had to change the paste line to `pyautogui.hotkey("command", "v")`

Comment: beautiful example

Answer (score 4):

I tried trestlnord's answer, but it did not work. I adapted the idea to this:

```
import pyautogui as px

def type_unicode(word):
    for char in word:
        num = hex(ord(char))
        px.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'u')
        for n in num:
            px.typewrite(n)
        px.typewrite('\n')
```

works on arch linux

Comment: the only piece of code that worked in my case. My piece of code also included 
```
with open("text.txt") as f:
    for row in f:
        for char in row:
 ...```

Comment: but it's  too slow

Answer (score 2):

Try `pynput` instead I found it more easy to type Unicode text. Install it using `pip install pynput` or `pip3 install pynput`

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.type("Næst")
```

Comment: I wat trying to type Thai characters and didn't find any way to do this with pyautogui even after changing the keyboard layout. pynput worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import time 
time.sleep(3)
Controller().type("Næst")
```

This code works perfectly. Just need to install pynput with pip command.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyperclip
import pyautogui
from time import sleep


def TextAuto(myText):
    i = 0
    f = 0
    for char in myText:
        f += 1
        if char in 'áéíóúâêôãõçàÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÔÃÕÇÀ':
            pyautogui.typewrite(myText[i:f], interval=0.04)
            i = f
            pyperclip.copy(char)
            pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
    if i != f:
        pyautogui.typewrite(myText[i:f], interval=0.04)

sleep(4)
TextAuto("""áéíóúâêôãõçàÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÔÃÕÇÀ""")
```

This code works, just install pyautogui.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).