# How to get python to typewrite "ß"

Tags: python, decode, pyautogui, pynput

The typewrite is not typing out the "ß" despite using .decode

I have tried using other words like

> typewrite("Hello World")

and they worked fine. So it is a problem with the typing rather than detection of the keyboard inputs

This is my current code

`

```
from pyautogui import *
from pynput import keyboard
keyNo = 0
def on_press(key):
    global keyNo
    if key == keyboard.Key.alt_l:
        keyNo = 1
    if keyNo == 1 and key == keyboard.KeyCode(char="s"):
        typewrite("ß")
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
listener = mouse.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
```

`

I was hoping that I could press "ALT + S" on my keyboard and it would type out a "ß". However it does nothing no errors.

Comment: Did you include a shebang at the front showing an encoding that allows for the scharfes S?

Comment: # -*- coding: utf8 -*- ? Yes, sorry. If that is not it then no

Comment: This github link may be helpful to you: https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/94

Comment: @KaiwenChen That is needed in Python 2, but in Python 3 utf-8 is the default.

Comment: Still Stumped, not sure what do next

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33152754/355230) to a somewhat related question might be helpful.