# Typewrite ! character with pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

This works to simulate the keystrokes:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.typewrite('hello world!', interval=0.1)
```

except that:

- it writes `hello world§` (with FR keyboard layout)
- it writes `hello world` (with EN keyboard layout)

Of course, the desired output should be `hello world!`.

Is there a workaround?

NB: I don't think it is the same problem than [Input unicode string with pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151865/input-unicode-string-with-pyautogui) because here it's not a non-ASCII character, but anyway the main answer with a copy/paste hack would not work in my case, as I really want the slow typing with 100ms pause between each keypress.

[image]

[image]

Here is how to reproduce the error:

- Windows 7 x64
- Python 3.6 or Python 2.7
- pyautogui 0.9.41 or 0.9.48
- the 2 lines of code mentioned at the beginning

Comment: [The documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-typewrite-function) shows an example printing `'Hello world!'`, which contains a `!`. It doesn't look like you need to do anything special. Can you provide more information about your environment?

Comment: @Chris I have a standard Windows 7 x64, Python 3.6, pyautogui 0.9.41 ; I tested with both french keyboard layout and english. I updated the question with a screencast. I have no other program running (no autohotkey or similar running at the same time).

Comment: This is working for me. It prints `!` as expected. Are you on windows? Did you try deleting the explanation point and entering it again manually?

Comment: @Jortega, Yes I tried that. I'm on Windows, and you? I just upgraded to pyautogui 0.9.48 and it's the same :/  I also tried with Py2.7 and it's the same: https://gget.it/xrig/a.gif

Comment: I just tried on another (very standard) Windows 7 x64 computer + Python3.6 + Pyautogui 0.9.48 and it's the same.

Comment: it doesn't send asci chars `!` to programs - it sends to system keyboard's codes for key `1` which in standard layout is also used for `!` and system decide what char send to program. If your system has non-standard layout then system may send wrong char. If your layout has assigned `§` to key `1` then system will send `§` to program. Probably only using clipboad you can send it correctly. If you will use clipboar to copy single char and use `time.sleep(0.1)` between chars then you can get similar result.

Comment: Not sure if related, but can you also specify your region/locale settings?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't send ascii char `!` to program - it sends keyboard's code to system (probably code for key `1` which in standard layout is used for char `!`) and system decides what char send to program. If your system has non-standard layout then system may send wrong char.

Probably only using clipboad you can send it correctly. If you will use clipboard to copy single char and wait `0.1s` between chars then you can get similar result.

```
import time
import pyperclip
import pyautogui

time.sleep(2)

for char in 'Hello World!':
    pyperclip.copy(char)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v', interval=0.1)
```

---

**BTW:** using `print(pyautogui.__file__)` you can find folder with source code and in file `_pyautogui_win.py` you can see what key codes it uses in `Windows`.

You should see key codes assigned to chars using also

Window:

```
print(pyautogui._pyautogui_win.keyboardMapping)
```

Linux:

```
print(pyautogui._pyautogui_x11.keyboardMapping)
```

Maybe if you change values in `keyboardMapping` then it will send it correctly but for every layout you would have to set different values.

For example on Linux this

```
import pyautogui

#pyautogui._pyautogui_win.keyboardMapping['!'] = 12
pyautogui._pyautogui_x11.keyboardMapping['!'] = 12

pyautogui.typewrite('!!!')
```

gives me `###` instead of `!!!`

Comment: Hi @furas. How did you guess that the value `12` would fix the issue? I'm trying to display this caracter `~`.

Comment: @Daishi number `12` is keycode (scancode) for key `3` on my QWERTY (US-Keyborad) and it was only example to show how to change it but it is not correct value to get `!`. It gives `#` - at least on QWERTY (US-Keyboard). On my QWERTY (US-Keyboard) original number `10` gives correct `!` without any changes so I couldn't test it with other layouts. I wrote [program using PyGame or Tkinter to get keycode (scancode) for pressed/released key](https://blog.furas.pl/how-to-get-keycode-in-python-using-tkinter-or-pygame.html) and maybe it helps you to find correct value for different

Comment: In fact, the Ctrl-C - Ctrl-V trick is cruical, this should be incorporated into pyautogui as a sort of "rawtype" function.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue:

https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/38

> User on Windows 7, Python 3.4, running PyAutoGUI 0.9.30 and a French "AZERTY" keyboard reported being unable to simulate pressing :
>   Running the unit tests, they got these results:
>   [...]
>   a
>   ba
>   .Hello world§

https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/pull/55

https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/137

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your pyautogui module. If it doesn't work then try this code:

```
from pyautogui import *

typewrite("Hello World!")
keyDown("shift")
press("1")
keyUp("shift")
```

OR this code:

```
from pyautogui import *

a = "Hello World!"
typewrite(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your pyautogui module. If it doesn't work then try this code:

```
from pyautogui import *

typewrite("Hello World!")
keyDown("shift")
press("1")
keyUp("shift")
```

OR this code:

```
from pyautogui import *

a = "Hello World!"
typewrite(a)
```