# I don't get the word I uploaded when I output the code with Pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

When I write a word in my program, at the exit, I have another word different from the one I wrote. For example:

In command I write this => `pyautogui.typewrite ("who are you?")`
and in output I have ca => `zho qre youM`.
I have that `zho qre youM`, instead of `who are you?`

Comment: Pyautogui apparently doesn't handle non-US keyboard layouts very well - what you got is basically what a US typist would produce if they used a French keyboard without actually looking at the labels.  The only workaround I'm seeing is to use something like pyperclip to put the desired text on the cliboard, then use pyautogui to send Ctrl-V to paste it in.

Comment: similar problem with French keyboard [Typewrite ! character with pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604162/typewrite-character-with-pyautogui)