# I can't write arabic letters in pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, arabic, pyautogui, arabic-support

I was trying to make a spam bot using python but it doesn't work when I try to make it arabic but it works perfectly when I make it english I really need help quickly

This is the code

```
time.sleep(5)

f = open('spam.txt','r')
fa = f.encode("utf-8")
for word in fa:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

spam.txt
مرحبا

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"I was trying to make a spam bot"* I hope it never works. :-\

Comment: `it doesn't work` - what's the error?

Comment: I'm going to guess that this is some sort of problem with Unicode. Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33151865/8935887) yet?

Answer (score 2):

Pyautogui, I'm think, works of your keyboard and there for can't recognise some characters perhaps, I'm not sure but you can send it through a copy paste command like so.

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import time

time.sleep(5)

# Store our string to the clipboard
pyperclip.copy("مرحبا")
# Hotkey the paste command
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
```

Tested with into a text document and it is sending the characters just fine although it may depend on the app as to weather it will display left to right or right to left. From what I understand there are characters in Unicode that tell it what side to display if you need to.

For a spam bot put it into a text document read it then put each line in your clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pywinauto library instead. It works perfectly.
Try this:

```
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys

time.sleep(1)
send_keys(' سلام {ENTER 2}some more textt{BACKSPACE}', with_spaces=True)
```

remeber to add this library with

> pip install pywinauto

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately,  the Pyautogui doesn't support Arabic or Persian languages, for solve this problem you can type a word in TextPad then copy this manually and use hotkey to do this

```
from pyautogui import click, press, hotkey
# text 
def type():
            click(1000,701)
            hotkey("ctrl","v")
            press("enter")
            sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this

```
msg=pyperclip.copy("اسپم")
for n in range(10):
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl","v")
    pyautogui.press("Enter") 
    time.sleep(0.5)
```