# Turkish characters in pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui, turkish

How can I add Turkish characters to pyautogui typewrite function?

I am copying the Turkish word and then using the pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v') to write Turkish characters but is there any other way?

Comment: Maybe these are useful for you; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151865/input-unicode-string-with-pyautogui and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66405835/i-cant-write-arabic-letters-in-pyautogui

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input unicode string with pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151865/input-unicode-string-with-pyautogui)