# How to avoid Python to transform backlash (\) in less-than sign (<) in directory address?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a folder, which I'm trying to input in Python as a string, for example `folder = r'C:\Users\Desktop'`  or `folder = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop'` 
I'm then using `pyautogui.typewrite(folder)`, but when I do so the directory name is pasted as `C'<Users<Desktop` 
Do you know what is causing that and how can I solve this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: What's your keyboard layout?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151865/input-unicode-string-with-pyautogui

Comment: I'm always changing between languages (German/English/Portuguese). Usually when I'm coding I set it in german, which is my original keyboard configuration. I'll have a look at this link you shared.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution]

Combining both inputs from "SuperStormer" (thanks a lot!!) along with some additional research and adaptation I manage to solve the issue by:

1. Change the keyboard to English - looks like pyautogui emulates the typing of the keyboard, and it doesn't support any language other than english - this almost solved my issue, it solved the backslashes, but then the ":" started to become a "?", like `'C?\Users\Desktop'`
2. Use pyperclip to paste string directly from keyboard - I did some simulations and that would have worked, except that I already had something on my clipboard that had to be used in a later step, and as I couldn't find a way to reference more than two clipboards at a time that didn't work right away, but after some workarounds based on that function I finally got to the solution